# Javascript does not work after using JQuery .load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple cart system which shows all the products in the user's cart. The user can update the quantity of that cart from the cart page.

When a user updates the quantity, an ajax call is made which updates the value in the database and afterwards it reloads the div with so all updates are reflected.

Two issues occur:
1. The div for some reason gets created again in the same div. I don't know why. So in this case `#menuContent` is created again inside `#menuContent` such that:

```
<div class="row" id="menuContent">
   <div class="row" id="menuContent">
      //php code to display list of items
   <div>
</div>
```

2. Afterwards, my javascript file stops working. I have a file called `site.js` which contains all my functions. It executes on page load but does not after the `.load()`

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row"  id="menuContent">

    <?php foreach($cartItems as $item): ?>
        <div class="col s12 m12 single-card">
            //Item information here and a button to update the cart. On button click, ajax call makes an update and on success it reloads the #mainContent div
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

This is what I'm using to reload the div:

```
$("#menuContent").load(location.href + " #menuContent");
```

Comment: How are you testing this? Remember that dynamically added content will not have appeared to the DOM when the page loaded, so JS/jQuery scripts that loaded up front may not be aware of the new elements.

Comment: `Javascript does not work after using JQuery .load() function`-> what javascript? please add code to clarify your question

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie It doesn't matter which javascript, the external js file with all the JS stops working completely.

Comment: I would suggest rather using a React approach where you reload the DOM after a state change in the domain. In this case it seems like the JS file is not in the appropriate directory in order for the page to reach it.